# ulimit -t Linux

Tags: linux, ulimit

I wrote two simple programs on Eclipse- Ubuntu to test ulimit terminal command (Their binaries are attached)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Iterator

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
for(long long i = 0;;i++)
cout << i << endl;
return 0;
}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Timer

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
clock_t start;
int main(){
start = clock();
for(long long i = 0;;i++)
cout << i << " in " << (double)(clock()-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "seconds" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
TESTING timer

```
+ulimit -t 0; '[PATH]\timer
```

**End of output**

```
116997 in 1.06seconds
Killed

'+ulimit -t 1; '[PATH]\timer
```

**End of output**

```
102501 in 0.96seconds
Killed

'+ulimit -t 2; '[PATH]\timer
```

**End of output**

```
[TEST 1]133073 in 1.19seconds
Killed
[TEST 2]101894 in 1seconds
Killed
[TEST 3]100950 in 0.96seconds
Killed
[TEST 4]126723 in 1.13seconds
Killed
[TEST 5 after opening a new terminal session]229302 in 2.14seconds
Killed

'+ulimit -t 5; '[PATH]\timer
```

**End of output**

```
**[TEST 1]219295 in 1.99seconds
Killed**
**[TEST 2 ater opening a new session]603088 in 5.47seconds
Killed**
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
TESTING iterator

```
+ulimit -t 0; '[PATH]\iterator'
```

**End of output**

```
200412
Killed

+ulimit -t 1; '[PATH]\iterator'
```

**End of output**

```
199462
Killed

+ulimit -t 2; '[PATH]\iterator'
```

**End of output**

```
206111
Killed

+ulimit -t 5; '[PATH]\iterator'
```

**End of output**

```
244284
Killed
```

what do you think is the problem?
It seems that a new terminal session sets a new timelimit
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On GNU/Linux, cpu limits can be set for all sessions in `/etc/security/limits.conf` config file, provided you mention pam_limits.so in your `pam` configuration

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. ulimit applies to descendants of the current shell, not unrelated processes.